# Resize Scroll Bar in QWebView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, scrollbar

I have a python application using PyQt. One of my widgets is a QWebView object and I need to make the vertical scroll bar wider. I've looked around but can't find a working solution. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I had seen this previously, was hoping for a more "elegant" solution I suppose. 
http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_change_the_width_of_the_scrollbar_of_qwebview

Anyways, my implementation of this in python looks like:

```
class style(QCommonStyle):
    ...
    def pixelMetric(self, metric, option=0, widget=0):
        current_style = QCommonStyle()
        if metric == QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent and widget == 0:
            return 16
        else:
            return current_style.pixelMetric(metric, option, widget)
```

And of course I'm calling

```
qApp.setStyle(style())
```

Separately.

My problem now is that only the background for the scrollbar gets drawn, not the scroll thumb or the scroll up/down buttons.

So is there a better way of resizing the scroll bar? Or did I miss something in the pixelMetric implementation?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_change_the_width_of_the_scrollbar_of_qwebview